# Rails ActiveRecord Multiple WHERE Statements

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have an array that contains some conditions, say:
`ages = [1, 4, 10]`.

I am trying to build a query where it will return the ages in the array. The array can be of arbitrary length. So something like:

```
Person.where("age == :ages", {:ages => ages})
```

Now this obviously does not work as `:ages` would be an array, when according to the equality statement above, it's expecting a string.

I'm trying to have it achieve something along the lines of: `WHERE age = 1 AND age = 4 AND age = 10` according to the `ages` array.

All examples online discuss how to use multiple where conditions when they are separate variables, in which case is easy as you would do: `Person.where("condition1 = :first AND condition2 = :second....)`. I have unknown number of items in the array and I want to filter all my query result by them.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers if it fits your questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already supported by ActiveRecord and the where statement:

```
ages = [1, 5, 12]
Person.where(age: ages)
# This will generates a query like:
# SELECT * FROM persons WHERE age IN(1, 5 ,12)
```

This way of querying is also better than 'hard-coding' condition (passing strings to the where statement). By using Hash parameters you let ActiveRecord deal with all the DB-Query translation work.

Comment: I was doing it as `Person.where(age => ages)` which is apparently incorrect. Could you explain the colon syntax? And what the hash form of `where` means please?

Comment: The colon is Ruby 1.9 optional syntax for a Hash. `{ :age => ages }` and `{ age: ages }` are functionally identical.

Comment: Except that you cant assign a string in the new Ruby 1.9 Hash Syntax: `{ 'foo' => 'bar' }` works when `{ 'foo': 'bar' }` does not.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for an `IN` query since `age` **cannot** be **both** `1` and `4` and `10` for some single column integer value.

```
Person.where(age: ages)
```

Comment: Nothing to do here but someone stole your profile picture on StackOverflow!